# Laravel Model binding of subclass model

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.5

I am having some trouble with route model binding my Eloquent subclass. The following code works fine:

```
$repo = new \App\Repositories\Eloquent\PluginRepository();
$plugin = $repo->findOrFail(1);
var_dump($plugin->type);
```

**Output**

```
object(App\PluginsTypes)#360 (26) {...}
```

But when I make a model bind, like this:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::resource('plugins', 'PluginsController');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Admin/PluginsController.php**

```
public function edit(PluginRepositoryInterface $plugin){
    var_dump($plugin); // object(App\Repositories\Eloquent\PluginRepository)#345 (26) {...}
    var_dump($plugin->id); // NULL
}
```

So the problem is, that it does not find the id passed in the route.

---

**Addition code in Laravel project:**

**app/Plugins.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Plugins extends Model{
    // My Eloquent Model

    /**
     * The foreignKey and ownerKey needs to be set, for the relation to work in subclass.
     */
    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo(PluginsTypes::class, 'plugin_type_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/Repositories/SomeRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Abilities\HasParentModel;

class PluginsRepository extends Plugins{
    protected $table = 'some_table';

    use HasParentModel;
}
```

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Repositories\Providers\PluginRepositoryServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

**app/Repositories/Providers/PluginRepositoryServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PluginRepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    /**
     * This registers the plugin repository - added in app/config/app.php
     */
    public function register(){
        // To change the data source, replace the concrete class name with another implementation
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Repositories\Contracts\PluginRepositoryInterface',
            'App\Repositories\Eloquent\PluginRepository'
        );
    }
}
```

**Been using these resources:**

[HasParentModel Trait on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/calebporzio/a63b165b500d491a0c250eb5853e5d94)

[Extending Models in Eloquent](https://tighten.co/blog/extending-models-in-eloquent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the docs (of course):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding in the section **Customizing The Resolution Logic**

In my **app/Repositories/Providers/PluginRepositoryServiceProvider.php** i have added the following under my interface binding and it now works.

```
$this->app->router->bind('plugin', function ($value) {
        return \App\Repositories\Eloquent\PluginRepository::where('id', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

I will probably rename it, but it work like a charm :) Good day...